# Finding Duplicates with SQL? - Wring SQL Statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to see all rows where I have duplicated entries. But I do not see my failure. Does anybody know how I can solve this problem? - SQL says: `Unknown field cnt in where clause`.

I also tried `= 0` or even without the counter and the where condition but then it is working. And only without the where condition I also see `cnt` in my table but. Where is the error?

```
SELECT `name`, `price`, `shop`, `url`, `publisher`, `platform`, `category` Count(*) as cnt 
FROM `wp_all_import_xml`
WHERE cnt > 1
GROUP BY `name`, `price`, `shop`, `url`, `publisher`, `platform`, `category`
```

Picture: [image]

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: remove "where cnt >1" and replace with "having cnt > 1" and put it below the group by

Answer (score 1):

Use `HAVING` instead:

```
SELECT `name`, `price`, `shop`, `url`, `publisher`, `platform`, `category` Count(*) as cnt 
FROM `wp_all_import_xml`
GROUP BY `name`, `price`, `shop`, `url`, `publisher`, `platform`, `category`
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use having clauses

```
SELECT `name`, `price`, `shop`, `url`, `publisher`, `platform`, `category` Count(*) as cnt 
FROM `wp_all_import_xml`
GROUP BY `name`, `price`, `shop`, `url`, `publisher`, `platform`, `category`
having cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Groups are filtered with HAVING rows are filtere with WHERE

```
SELECT `name`, `price`, `shop`, `url`, `publisher`, `platform`, `category`, Count(*) as cnt 
FROM `wp_all_import_xml`
GROUP BY `name`, `price`, `shop`, `url`, `publisher`, `platform`, `category`
HAVING cnt>1
```

Comment: Getting #1064 error...https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzLxINxZFzovb0J0ZEJ1aVUyOGs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Jan missed a comma after category

Comment: THANK YOU ALL! :)